# How to store command line arguments for future use?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a big bash script `(version 3.2.51(1)-release)` and I need to store command line arguments for use in the script.

I checked many threads here and people suggested to use "$@" to access all arguments.

If I run this script (test.sh) -

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@";

$> ./test.sh 1 2 3
1 2 3
```

But if i run this

```
#!/bin/bash
set args1 = "$@";

... do some work here ...

echo $args1;
```

I get no output when run. What am I missing here?
I want to store the arguments without modifying them and then use them sometime later in the script.

Comment: `set var = value` isn't bash for starters. bash shell assignments do not allow spaces around the `=` sign. You cannot store an array (like `"$@"`) in a string (like `$args`) safely (if you care about arguments with spaces/etc. in the names).

Comment: What makes you think the arguments are going to disappear? Unless you use `shift` for some reason, the script's arguments are there for the duration of the script.

Comment: @rici : Correct, the problem was something different, the solution is given below.

Comment: So you are manipulating the positional parameters with `shift` or `set` at some point in the script then?

Comment: Yes, that was my bad - I was using `set` . Thank you for that correction above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Store all the arguments in an array:

```
args=("$@")
```

Then print them as:

```
printf "%s\n" "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Just one question - is there a way to store all arguments as a string?

Comment: Storing them as plain string is error prone for arguments that contain spaces. Your code can be called as `./script "foo bar" a b` also.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
args1="$*"
```

instead of `set args1 = "$@";` if you want all arguments as a single string.

Note: Try to use your variables double quoted, otherwise you will loose white spaces.

Or if you want to treat each one of them differently then you need an array:

```
argarr=("$@")
```

Then you can access each element of the array with `"${argarr[$index]}"` and all element at once with `"${argarr[@]}"`

Comment: Although @EtanReisner has pointed it out correctly, it solves my specific problem for now. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Quoted expansion of `"$args1"` gets you a single word of all the arguments. Unquoted expansion of `$args1` gets you multiple words (but not the original ones). You cannot get the original arguments back.